# Bootstrap - menu is too wide on smartphone

Tags: html, css

The menu is displayed correctly on the desktop computer's screen. However, when I run a page on the phone, the menu is too wide (out of the screen) and I can not adjust it to the screen resolution. The html code looks like:

```
<!-- Start Header Section -->
<header class="main_menu_sec navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                <div class="lft_hd">
                    <a href="http://cybid.com.pl/"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
                </div>
            </div>          
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12">
                <div class="rgt_hd">                    
                    <div class="main_menu">
                        <nav id="nav_menu">
                        <div id="navbar">

                            <ul>
                                ...
                            </ul>
...
</header>
```

How to implement some changes for smaller resolution then PC screens? How to change the code?

Thank you for response in advance.

Comment: Please make a code sample out of this and include your css.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using [@media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) in your CSS file?

These allow you to change the style based on parameters such as the screen width.

For, example, if I wanted to change the style of an element with a maximum screen width of 480px, I could write:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     -your styles here-
}
```

For your code, you could run a media query on the main menu class and perhaps try to eliminate margin:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     .main_menu {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I hope this is a helpful starting point- If you have any questions let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. I put too wide div in different section without optimize it for media resolutions.

Now all is fine.